# is it advisable to use the same template ref value in dynamically loaded component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxt3

```
//parent.vue
<component
      ref="stepForm"
      :key="currentTabComponent.id"
       :is="currentTabComponent.value"
        @success="handleSuccess"
 ></component>
const stepForm=ref('stepForm')
```

This is my implementation of tab component where different component are loaded on different scenarios. All the child components have a same validate method exposed which are meant to be called from parent component. Is it okay to use same ref for different child components that are loaded dynamically from a computed value?

My goal is to call `stepForm.value.validate()` of the current component that is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes

As long as each child component has its own `.id` which you pick up in the line

```
 :key="currentTabComponent.id"
```

then when that `.id` and therefore `:key` changes, the component will re-render and your `ref('stepform')` will point to the new component.

#### But if you store a constant reference, it will be out of date

Therefore instead of

```
const stepForm = ref('stepform')
```

Just use

```
ref('stepform')
```

throughout your code where you would otherwise use the `stepform` constant. This should keep the reference dynamic.

Comment: stepForm.value.validate() works in the first component, but as soon as the other component is loaded, it is undefined. Could you help me find what am I missing?
@eureka

Comment: Ah! I forgot that you were storing the reference to the old "stepform". I suggest using ref('stepform') throughout, thereby always getting the most recent one?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your response. Does using let instead of const could also fix that?
Do you mean I should use ref("stepForm").value.validate() instead of stepForm.value.validate()?
Could you also please point me to any example if you have any? 

 @Eureka

Comment: Q1. No, using `let` instead of `const` won't fix it, because using `let` does not cause the variable to automatically update: you have to update it manually. Q2. Yes I am saying that you should use `ref("stepForm").value.validate()`, and get rid of the `stepForm` variable. Instead of the variable, which you would have to keep updating, use `ref("stepForm")` which will always be correct.